# The number of values of (x,y)?

Tags: trigonometry

The number of values of $(x,y)\epsilon (0,2\pi)$ for which $$\sin (x-y)+\cos(x-y)=0$$
My approach is as follows.

By observation we see that $x-y=3\pi/4, 7\pi/4...n\pi-\pi/4 $

Hence shouldn't there be infinite such $x$ and $y$ in the interval?

Comment: Yup, you are correct.

Comment: Thanks just wanted to confirm!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes

If $x,y \in [0,2\pi)$ then $x-2\pi \lt y \lt x+2\pi$

Meanwhile $\sin (x-y)+\cos(x-y) = 2\sin(\frac\pi 4)\sin(x-y+\frac14 \pi)$, which is zero when $\sin(x-y+\frac14 \pi)=0$

so the solutions are of the form of line segments:

- $y=x+\frac54 \pi$ with $0 \le x \lt \frac34 \pi$ and $\frac54 \pi \le y \lt 2 \pi$
- $y=x+\frac14 \pi$ with $0 \le x \lt \frac74 \pi$ and $\frac14 \pi \le y \lt 2 \pi$
- $y=x-\frac34 \pi$ with $\frac34 \pi \le x \lt 2\pi$ and $0  \le y \lt \frac54 \pi$
- $y=x-\frac74 \pi$ with $\frac74 \pi \le x \lt 2\pi$ and $0  \le y \lt \frac14 \pi$

Answer (score 2):

Set $z=x-y$. Then the equation turns into $\tan z=-1$ which has solution $z=-\frac{\pi}{4}+k\pi$.

Comment: Hence an infinite x,y could be z in the interval right?

Comment: Absolutely. Choose $z=\frac{3}{4}\pi$ and fix, for example $x=0$, $y=\frac{3}{4}\pi$. Then for any $\epsilon>0$, the pair $(x+\epsilon,y+\epsilon)$ is also a solution ($\epsilon<\frac{5}{4}\pi$ of course).